# How to grep, excluding some patterns?

Tags: bash, grep

I'd like find lines in files with an occurrence of some pattern and an absence of some other pattern. For example, I need find all files/lines including `loom` except ones with `gloom`. So, I can find `loom` with command:

```
grep -n 'loom' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

Now, I want to search `loom` excluding `gloom`. However, both of following commands failed:

```
grep -v 'gloom' -n 'loom' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
grep -n 'loom' -v 'gloom' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

What should I do to achieve my goal?

***EDIT 1:*** I mean that `loom` and `gloom` are the character sequences (not necessarily the words). So, I need, for example, `bloomberg` in the command output and don't need `ungloomy`.

***EDIT 2:*** There is sample of my expectations.
Both of following lines are in command output:

> I faced the icons that *loomed* through the veil of incense.
>
> Arty is *slooming* in a *gloomy* day.

Both of following lines aren't in command output:

> It’s *gloomyin’* ower terrible — great muckle doolders o’ cloods.
>
> In the south west round of the heigh pyntit hall

Comment: Are you looking for files that match your criteria of lines that match your criteria?

Comment: I'm looking for files with lines matching my criteria. And I want to see list of all sets filename + number of matching line + matching line itself.

Comment: If the line was `there is a loom in the gloom` - would you want that line printed? Just trying to understand if you're just looking for lines where loom occurs other than as part of gloom or if you really do want to exclude lines containing gloom even when loom appears on it's own elsewhere on the line. Posting some sample input and expected output would help.

Comment: So your question is really `How do I find lines containing the string "loom" where "loom" is not preceded by the letter "g"`? If you'd posted some sample input and desired output that would have helped a lot. The answer to that question is included in the answers below.

Comment: @EdMorton - Yes, you're right - I need all lines, where occurs `loom` without preceded `g`. (I'm sorry. I started to comment yesterday, but never finished. Accidentally this comment was sent.)

Comment: At the beginning of you question, you said you want lines with a `loom` and absence of `gloom`. But if your **Edit 2**, the second sample output, there is both `loom` in `slooming` and `gloom` in `gloomy` day, why?

Comment: @Juto - I added **Edit 2**, because understood that original wording was confusing.

Comment: I still seems to be confusing to me, so are the answers from below any good? I can see some reasonable ones?

Comment: @Juto - Yes, some of answers are good. I did not decide what of them to accept, yet.

Answer (score 130):

How about just chaining the greps?

```
grep -n 'loom' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp) | grep -v 'gloom'
```

Comment: Just in time. Works Perfectly. -v is the option to exclude. Thanks

Comment: From the question: _So, I need, for example, `bloomberg` in the command output and don't need `ungloomy`._  If a single line contained '… and bloomberg is ungloomy about the prospects…', you would eliminate that line but it is wanted (because if contains `bloomberg`).

Answer (score 27):

Another solution without chaining `grep`:

```
egrep '(^|[^g])loom' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

Between brackets, you exclude the character `g` before any occurrence of `loom`, unless `loom` is the first chars of the line.

Comment: for beginners like me who wonder what is `egrep`: it's an alias for `grep -E` (source: `man grep`).

Answer (score 12):

A bit old, but oh well...

The most up-voted solution from @houbysoft will not work as that will exclude any line with "gloom" in it, even if it has "loom". According to OP's expectations, we need to include lines with "loom", even if they also have "gloom" in them. This line needs to be in the output "Arty is slooming in a gloomy day.", but this will be excluded by a chained grep like

```
grep -n 'loom' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp) | grep -v 'gloom'
```

Instead, the [egrep regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18469038) example of [Bentoy13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507014/bentoy13) works better

```
egrep '(^|[^g])loom' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

as it will include any line with "loom" in it, regardless of whether or not it has "gloom". On the other hand, if it only has gloom, it will not include it, which is precisely the behaviour OP wants.

Answer (score 9):

Just use awk, it's much simpler than grep in letting you clearly express compound conditions.

If you want to skip lines that contains both `loom` and `gloom`:

```
awk '/loom/ && !/gloom/{ print FILENAME, FNR, $0 }' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

or if you want to print them:

```
awk '/(^|[^g])loom/{ print FILENAME, FNR, $0 }' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

and if the reality is you just want lines where `loom` appears as a word by itself:

```
awk '/\<loom\>/{ print FILENAME, FNR, $0 }' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

Comment: Think about how you'd write a grep command to get lines that contain `abc` and `def` and `ghi` in any order. Now compare that to `awk '/abc/ && /def/ && /ghi/'`. Now think about how the grep equivalent of `awk '/loom/ && !/gloom/'` is being written in the answers on this page.

Comment: I am not very familiar with awk, apparently there are books about this command on its own. For now I am fine with grep, maybe one day I will say the same thing you did. :)

Comment: awk is THE standard UNX tool (i.e. available on ALL UNIX installations) for processing text files. That's what it was invented to do and it's very good at it. If you're on UNIX and parsing text files, learn awk from the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition by Arnold Robins. There's a small paradigm shift to get over related to awks `condition { action }` syntax but then it's a breeze for anyone with any C or other Algol-base language experience.

Comment: Bonus: output like `grep -Hn --color`: `awk '/loom/ && !/gloom/ { gsub(/loom/, color("1;31") "&" color(0)); print color(35) FILENAME color(36) ":" color(32) FNR color(36) ":" color(0) $0; }; function color(c) { return "\033[" c "m"; }'`

Answer (score 7):

`-v` is the "inverted match" flag, so piping is a very good way:

`grep "loom" ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)| grep -v "gloom"`

Answer (score 6):

Simply use! `grep -v` multiple times.

#Content of file

```
[root@server]# cat file
1
2
3
4
5
```

#Exclude the line or match

```
[root@server]# cat file |grep -v 3
1
2
4
5
```

#Exclude the line or match multiple

```
[root@server]# cat file |grep -v "3\|5"
1
2
4
```

Comment: yes but how could you itterate through a set of similar files. I would not want to run this command 1000 times if I want to check 1000 files

Answer (score 5):

/*You might be looking something like this?

```
grep -vn "gloom" `grep -l "loom" ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)`
```

The BACKQUOTES are used like brackets for commands, so in this case with `-l` enabled,
the code in the BACKQUOTES will return you the file names, then with -vn to do what you wanted: have filenames, linenumbers, and also the actual lines.

**UPDATE** Or with xargs

```
grep -l "loom" ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp) | xargs grep -vn "gloom"
```

Hope that helps.*/

Please ignore what I've written above, it's rubbish.

```
grep -n "loom" `grep -l "loom" tt4.txt` | grep -v "gloom"

               #this part gets the filenames with "loom"
#this part gets the lines with "loom"
                                          #this part gets the linenumber,
                                          #filename and actual line
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `grep -P` (perl regex) supported `negative lookbehind`:

```
grep -P '(?<!g)loom\b' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

I added `\b` for word boundaries.

Comment: You don't need a lookbehind, `\([^g]\|^\)` works. And this doesn't exclude lines with both `loom` and `gloom`.

Comment: @Kevin: OP wants to find lines with loom but `not gloom`.

Comment: Exactly. If a line has both, he doesn't want it but this will match it anyway.

Comment: @Kevin: This will NOT match gloom but will match loom (as OP wants).

Comment: From the question: _So, I need, for example, `bloomberg` in the command output and don't need `ungloomy`._  Thus, the word boundaries are counterproductive.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -n 'loom' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp) | grep -v 'gloom'
```

Comment: From the question: _So, I need, for example, `bloomberg` in the command output and don't need `ungloomy`._  If a single line contained '… and bloomberg is ungloomy about the prospects…', you would eliminate that line but it is wanted (because if contains `bloomberg`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "I need find all files/lines including loom except ones with gloom."

Answer (score 0):

Question: search for 'loom' excluding 'gloom'. 
Answer:

```
grep -w 'loom' ~/projects/**/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

Comment: From the question: _So, I need, for example, `bloomberg` in the command output and don't need `ungloomy`._  I don't think that `-w` is the solution to that conundrum.